Grip & Electric Truck Equation
This puzzle comes from a Facebook post, and has also been shared on Reddit.
There's a truck with the below "equation" etched into its bumper.  The truck belonged to a Grip and Electric crew; so the equation's likely related to their work.

For the visually impaired (and search engines), the equation is:

an image of a hammer divided by a right angle (represented as left and lower sides of a square with a curve crossing both lines to indicate an angle) to the power G.
Plus 60Hz followed by an image of 3 sine waves against a dotted line/x axis (of the sine waves 2 are in anti-phase with one another, the third with peaks & troughs when the others are on the 0 line).  This sine image is to the power of epsilon (ε).
Equals C (presumably the constant representing the speed of light?)

There's no more info, so it's not clear if this is a rebus, an equation, or some other kind of puzzle.

I think it's not so much an equation as something that looks like an equation.
The first term is "hammer and right angles" and is labelled (not raised to the power of) G - the Grip of their name.
The second term is an electrical frequency and a phase diagram and is labelled E - the Electric of their name.
The arithmetic symbols are just to make it look equationy.
The C is probably the speed of light "we're really fast, as fast as can be" but it could also be C for Company or Crew.

Ah nice - that's the best explanation I've heard so far; good shout.  Since I'm not certain what the real answer is, I'll leave it until the end of the week before marking the best answer as solving it; but suspect that will be you :)
